# What causes SQL Server CE error "Lock cannot be acquired for a referred object"

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-ce

I have a C# project which inserts records into a SQL Server CE 4.0 database which has been running ok for about 18 months.

At some point while the program was running yesterday all INSERT queries started producing the following error.

> Lock cannot be acquired for a referred object. The page which
>   contains the referred object is already freed by another concurrent
>   session.

Restarting the application and restarting the machine did not fix the error.

Deleting and recreating the database did fix the error.

I have since moved the original database file to another machine and the same error is occurring when attempting to run an INSERT query.

```
INSERT Message (TimeStamp, Message) VALUES ('01/01/2017 09:15:32 AM', 'test');
```

Google is not turning up any results when searching for this error.

Does anyone know what the error means and what causes it? How can I programmatically handle this error?

Thank you

Comment: it seems your sql objects are getting locked, not the c# one.

Comment: have you verified the DB file?: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceengine.verify.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396  Otherwise, go to your source control repository and see what code changes have been made....

Comment: @DirtyDeveloper - I have verified the database using the method linked. It returned True (database is ok).

Comment: @MitchWheat - No code changes for over 12 months. The error occurred while the application was running.

Comment: @Mark , its tough to understand your issue. can you please tell me how you caught this error? in DB or on code side in catch block? if its in catch block can you please provide the detailed exception details i.e stack trace ,error code ,inner exception etc.

Comment: database size over 4GB?

Comment: What is the database file size, and what is your connection string?

Comment: @ErikEJ Hello Erik, I ask [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48167307/492258), later on I realized it is dup of above question. so per your comment I triend many variations, such as 1024 for max db size and fill that db and also max size: 4091 . But the issue not related those cases. Could you give ideas about issue. Thanks